# How do I erase contents of file upload if regular expression validation fires?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my regular expression validator control for the file upload

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regfileuploadimages1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Only picture files are allowed." ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.bmp|.BMP|.png|.PNG|.gif|.GIF|.jpg|.JPG|.jpeg|.JPEG)$" ControlToValidate="fileuploadimages1" Display="Dynamic" />
```

From research here on stack overflow I know that I can use this to clear the file upload.

```
fileuploadimages1.Attributes.Clear();
```

What I want to happen is when a user tries to upload the wrong document type the validator fires and the file upload text clears so I thought of referencing the the control validator.

However, I am not sure what property to reference the validator by since both `enabled` and `visible` properties are set to true already, or if this is even the way to go about this.

Comment: Just out of user experience, why don't you just display an error and not remove it? It would be very frustrating if I clicked on the wrong file and had to navigate my system for that file again.

Comment: oh, and doesn't `fileuploadimages1` have to be `regfileuploadimages1`?

Comment: No. The name of the validator is `regfileuploadimages1` and the name of the control it validates is `fileuploadimages1`. If it was named incorrectly the validator would not fire at all, but it works. I was only wanting to clear it out when it fired as a little extra feature.